# Matching words with @ symbol and ignore

Tags: php, regex

I'm writing a script that runs through users comments, breaks the comments into individual words, and adds these words to a table in mysql. The reason is to find the words used most in the comments.

Also, I am matching the words to a list of words to ignore before adding to the table.

What I cant figure out, is how to also ignore any words with an @ symbol as a character in the word.

Here is what I currently have, its working except for matching the @

```
$added_count=0;
$words_to_forget = array();
$forget_words = "SELECT forget FROM word_bank_forget";
    $result = $conn->query($forget_words) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);    
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
            {
                $words_to_forget[] = $row['forget'];
            }

    $survey_words = "SELECT comments,clinic_id,sid FROM survey WHERE word_bank='0'";
        $result = $conn->query($survey_words) or die($conn->error.__LINE__);    
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    $comments = $row['comments'];
                    $clinic_id = $row['clinic_id'];
                    $sid = $row['sid'];
                    $wordChunks = explode(" ", $comments);
                    for($i = 0; $i < count($wordChunks); $i++){
                        $broken_word = strtolower($wordChunks[$i]);
                        $broken_word = str_replace(array('.', ''), '' , $broken_word);
                        $broken_word = str_replace(array(',', ''), '' , $broken_word);
                        if ($broken_word != '' ){
                            if (!in_array($broken_word, $words_to_forget)) {
                                mysql_query("INSERT into word_bank (word,clinic_id) values ('$broken_word','$clinic_id')");
                                $added_count++;
                                }
                        mysql_query("UPDATE survey SET word_bank='1' WHERE sid='$sid'");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

I have tried using a regex, but cant get this to work.
I can match the @ symbol with /\@/ but cant seem to tell php to ignore the word if there is a match.

Maybe something along these lines (Not working):

```
$pattern = '/\@/';
if !preg_match($pattern, $broken_word){

}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (strpos($word, '@') !== false)`

Comment: That is so much easier!